# Why don't we write general linear second order ODEs as $P(x)u''(x) + Q(x)u'(x) + R(x)u(x) = g(x)$ instead of $u''(x) + q(x)u'(x) + r(x)u(x) = g(x)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The general form of the second order linear ODE is:

$$u''(x) + q(x)u'(x) + r(x)u(x) = g(x)$$

In particular, note that any function dependent on $t$ multiplied by $u''(x)$ has been divided out, to leave $1$ in front of $u''(x)$. Why do we do this? Wouldn't it be more general to write:

$$P(x)u''(x) + Q(x)u'(x) + R(x)u(x) = g(x)$$

...that is, *not* divide out $P(t)$? What guarantee do we have that $P(t)$ is non-zero for all $t$ in the interval of interest, which allows us to divide it out?

Comment: You don't: that's what singular points are for: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_singular_point
 (Whereas if it is zero on an interval, then your equation is not second-order in that interval, so it acts very differently)

Comment: I believe you mix up dependencies on $x$ and $t$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faced with
$$
P(x)u''(x) + Q(x)u'(x) + R(x)u(x) = g(x)
$$
if $P(x_0) \ne 0$ I can divide:
$$
u''(x) + \frac{Q(x)}{P(x)}u'(x) + \frac{R(x)}{P(x)} u(x) = \frac{g(x)}{P(x)} \\
u''(x) + \hat{Q}(x)u'(x) + \hat{R}(x) u(x) = \hat{g}(x)
$$
If $P(x_0) = 0$ I would analyze the order-reduced equation instead
$$
Q(x)u'(x) + R(x)u(x) = g(x)
$$
and again either get a normal form DE or another reduction. In the end one always deals with a normal form or the condition $g(x) = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends what source you're working with.  A lot of elementary differential equations texts will say that the general form for a second-order ODE is the more general $$P(x)u''(x)+Q(x)u'(x)+R(x)u(x)=g(x)$$ that you quoted.

The right question to answer is: does it make sense to talk about solutions of a differential equation such as $u''(x)+q(x)u'(x)+r(x)u(x)=g(x)$, satisfying the initial condition $u(0)=a$, $u'(0)=b$, if one of $q(0)$, $r(0)$, or $g(0)$ is not defined?  Consider Bessel's equation of order 1: $$x^2u''+xu'+(x^2-1)u=0.$$  It can be shown that this differential equation does have a solution $u(x)$ that satisfies $u(0)=0$, $u'(0)=1$, even though, if we divide both sides of the equation by $x^2$ to bring it into the "standard form", we get a division by zero at $x=0$.  This is called a singular point, although it is regular.

In short, it depends who you ask.  I've seen the "standard form" defined both ways.